# Manage multiple request at the same time to spring mvc controller method

Tags: spring, python-requests

I am developing a spring mvc web app with more than 70 entities. I am confused how to manage below problem. How can I manage multiple requests from different sessions comes at the same time to the method in the controller?
Identity is not "unique", I check it with manuel "status".

```
@Repository
public class RecordDAOImpl implements RecordDAO {

    @Override
    public void create(Dialog obj) {
        getCurrentSession().save(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExist(String identity) {
        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("identity", identity));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("status", "DELETED")));
        if (!criteria.list().isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I manage multiple requests from different sessions comes at the same time to the method in the controller? - No worries, it's the job of Web Container.

Comment: yes it is job webcontainer and spring web to handle them, if you are worried about highload of request coming in you need to think in terms of load balancing

Comment: But, when I try myself and send multiple request at the same time, I can create record with the same identity. I dont want this happen.

Comment: Very old post but before creating a new one, with the same issue, I'm wondering if you finally found the solution, did you?